# Cauchy Sequence of Differentials and Point-Wise Limits

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $D\subseteq R^2$ be an open and connected subset, and $\{f_{n} | D\to R^2\}$ a sequence of differentiable functions.

Suppose that $\{(Df_{n}) | D\to Hom(R^2,R^2)\}$, the sequence of Jacobians, is uniformly cauchy; $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $ \exists k \in N $ s.t $\forall n,m>k$ and $\forall x\in D$ $||(Df_n(x)) - (Df_m(x))||<\epsilon$ for $||*||$ denotes some operator norm.

Also assuming that for some $x_{0} \in D$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x_{0}) = a \in R^2$

Then there exists the point-wise limit for all $x \in D$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x) \in R^2$

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do:

Basically I want to use $a$ as an anchor, and write

$f_{n}(x_{0}) - f_n(x) - o(||x-x_{0}||) = (Df_{n})(x)(x_{0}-x)$

then try to estimate; $||(Df_{n})(x) - (Df_{m})(x)|| = ||f_{n}(x_{0}) - f_{m}(x_{0}) + f_m(x) - f_n(x)|| $ and try to conclude that the sequence $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is cauchy too.

Can you please comment on the direction I've written, and if you think it isn't correct please guide?

Thanks for the help!